# How do you access a model attribute in jquery?

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm adding an object to my `ModelAndView` in spring and forwarding to my jsp view.  I need to access that object in my jquery.  Is this possible without first putting the value in a hidden field?  How is it done?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var modelAttributeValue = '${modelAttribute}';
</script>
```

This will resolve the model attribute added by `model.addAttribute("modelAttribute", value)`

Comment: hmm. this does not work when the jquery function is a part of a js file that is imported into the UI template

Comment: How can I set a modelAttribute property?

Answer (score 3):

probably, you can save the model attribute in a hidden field and access it onload as below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var modelAttr = $("#modelAttr").val();
  alert(modelAttr);
}

input type="hidden" id="modelAttr" name="modelAttr" value="${modelAttribute}"/>
```

Add c:out around the `${modelAttribute}` in the jsp.

Comment: Only this solution works in my case (Spring+Thymeleaf+JS). Passing a String is no problem, but how can I pass a list or an array of Strings?

Answer (score 1):

In java controller,

```
model.addAttribute("key", "value");
```

inside jQuery,

```
let name = [[${key}]];
console.log("modelAttributeValue: ", name)
```