# Access to the variable I put in the model in my jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

i want to access in my jquery script to the variable `cardlist` i put in the model:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchlostcard") 
public  
String searchlostcard(@ModelAttribute(value="searchform") SearchForm searchForm
        ,HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, Object> model) {   


    List<Lostcard> listlostcard = lostcardRepository.findByNom(searchForm.getValue());

    model.put("cardlist", listlostcard);

    return "search/results";

}
```

My jquery ajax call:

```
function searchAjax() {
$.ajax({
    url : 'searchlostcard',
    type: 'POST',
    data:$('#formSearch').serialize(),
    success : function(responce) {  

        /* how can i acces to my List of object (listlostcard) ? */
        $('#page_grid').html(responce);
    },      
    error : function(){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

}

Comment: You need to understand that Java is a server side component in this case, while javascript is a client side component. The `List` no longer exists on the client side.

Comment: but the variable it send with request. so we can get it from the client side.

Comment: The server response with an HTTP response which contains HTML content with nested javascript. The browser (the client) can execute the javascript. There is no concept of java object or variables at this point.

Comment: take a look at this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021383/how-do-you-access-a-model-attribute-in-jquery) i try it but i return me something wrong.

Comment: An expression like `${someBean}` returns the `toString()` value of that object.

Comment: so we can access to the variable, just we need to know how.

Comment: You aren't accessing the variable from javascript. The JSP is rendering the `${something}` expression into some String. The rendered text (which is simply HTML) is sent as the body of the HTTP response. Your browser receives that body, sees something like `var javascriptVar = "someText";`, evaluates it and executes it. **It's just text.**

Comment: thanks :) but i think always there a way. with json or something else.

Comment: That's another subject altogether. In that case, yes, javascript will process the JSON into some internal structure.

Comment: i try a solution over [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018124/difference-between-returning-modelandview-in-ajax-call) take a llook :)

Answer (score 1):

Change you method as:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchlostcard") 
@ResponseBody
public  
List<Lostcard> searchlostcard(@ModelAttribute(value="searchform") SearchForm searchForm
        ,HttpServletRequest request) {   


    List<Lostcard> listlostcard = lostcardRepository.findByNom(searchForm.getValue());

    return listlostcard ;

}
```

make sure you have Jackson Mapper in the classpath.
Then you can access the list in the success mehtod.

To use the response in the you can use:

```
success : function(responce) {  

    jQuery.each(response, function(i, val) {
                    alert(val.someProperty);
                });
}
```

Comment: And how is `$('#page_grid').html(responce);`supposed to work then?

Comment: It's not. I said the list can be accessed in the success method. You need to iterate over it...

Comment: So your solution isn't working or at least not complete. For the JavaScript part is still the same.

Comment: I updated the answer with Jquery example. pur JS can also be used. Instead of alert the result can be appended to the html. someProperty can be any Lostcard property.

Answer (score 0):

use Gson api to create a json string and put it in your model. to use Gson add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

then do this in your java code:

```
List<Lostcard> listlostcard = lostcardRepository.findByNom(searchForm.getValue());
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String json = gson.toJson(listlostcard);
model.put("cardlist", json);
return "search/results";
```

then read it in your js file like this:

```
success : function(responce) {  

    var cardlist = JSON.parse(responce);
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    for(var i=0;i<cardlist.length;i++){
        var row = tbl.insertRow(i);
        //let's say you have ID and title in your model
        var idCell = row.insertCell(0);
        idCell.innerHTML = cardlist[i]["ID"];
        var titlecell = row.insertCell(1);
        titlecell.innerHTML = cardlist[i]["title"];
    }
    $('#page_grid').append(tbl);
}
```

Comment: `responce` would still be HTML

Comment: yes `var cardlist = JSON.parse(responce);` `responce `is html !

Comment: no it is a json string if you want to convert it to html, first you have to decide how would you like to display your data, for instance in a table or a list...

Comment: So if if you know it doesn't work, why do you include it in your code?

Comment: I put it there just to print the json data as an string in the page. but if you want I can add another part to make it like a table.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out and let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: I think here the response variable will hold the html generated by the view that corresponds to "search/results"(also depends on the view resolver). So for this to work the JSP need just to print the model, isn't it?

Comment: yes you are right @Evgeni but i need to know the size of the list for some other stuff like test if there no result and make a `else ` to `$('#page_grid').html(responce);`

Comment: `var cardlist = JSON.parse(responce);` `responce` is view html.

Comment: You can use response.length to get the size.