# Difference between returning ModelAndView in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Why when i return a ModelAndView in a call ajax it works and display the jsp page normally but when when i return it into a map with other object it doesn't work.

First case which work:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchlostcard") 
public  @ResponseBody
ModelAndView searchlostcard() {             
    [...]   
return new ModelAndView("search/results","cardlist", listlostcard); ; 
}
```

My ajax call

```
[...]
success : function(responce) {              
    $('#page_grid').html(responce);
}
```

Second case which doesn't work:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchlostcard") 
public  @ResponseBody
Map<String, Object> searchlostcard() {          
    [...]   
    ModelAndView MaV = new ModelAndView("search/results","cardlist", listlostcard);

    Map<String, Object> modelino = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    modelino.put("taille", listlostcard.size());
    modelino.put("vue", MaV);

    return modelino ; 

}
```

My ajax call

```
[...]
success : function(responce) {          
     $('#page_grid').html(responce['vue']);
}
```

Comment: why would you put a ModelAndView into a model map? What's the client supposed to do with a ModelAndView object?

Comment: i didn't put in model map, i put it in a map to send other object with the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return a `ModelAndView` then Spring MVC **renders a view** and returns that **rendered view**, regardless of the `@ResponseBody` annotation. That is HTML (provided your view is HTML) is returned to the client.

Whereas when you return a `Map` and have an `@ResponseBody` annotation then Spring returns the **serialized object** (e.g. a JSON string representing the map). The view that is referenced by your `MaV` variable is not rendered in this case. That is you don't have any HTML returned to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently don't understand the concept of `@ResponseBody`. It does not trigger a JSP (or other view technology), but returns the Object itself, rendered to JSON, XML or whatever content negotiation is set up for.

You could try removing the annotation and see if it works.

Comment: yes i know if i remove the annotation and return a ModelAndView object it will work and display me the jsp page, but as you said it return a json or xml object so ModelAndView is a object and it will be returned as a json object so why the firt case in my subject work and second doesn't ?